# Angular 2: Push into array upon clicking an object

Tags: arrays, angular, events, mouseevent, push

When I click a row of object, I want it to be pushed into the `selectedProducts` array.

I have this in my typescript

```
selectedProducts: Product[] = [];

select(prod) {
    this.selectedProducts.push(prod);
    console.log(this.selectedProducts);   
}
```

but it only gets the first object I click in the user's side

Below is my HTML

```html
<div class="list-content fluid">
    <div class="products-cards" *ngFor="let product of dataSource['docs']">
        <app-product-card [product]="product" (click)="select(product)"></app-product-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have an *ngFor implemented? could you post that part? Also, 'first object' you mean the 'product' ?

Comment: This is actually a card. The ngFor is in another component.  @Vega

Comment: So I think selectedProducts must be in parent component, is not it?

Comment: So you click more than once but you have first product all time?

Comment: @Char can you char with us the parent and the child component code?

Comment: Okay so I already transferred it in parent component. Yes @SharikovVladislav I have first product all the time.

Comment: Row means card. This is a table but I am using card per row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to try this :

```
<div class="list-content fluid">
    <div class="products-cards" *ngFor="let product of dataSource['docs']"  (click)="select(product)">
        <app-product-card [product]="product"></app-product-card>
    </div>
</div>
```